# Look-up tables represented as enumerations in code

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, enums

I have a few look-up tables on the database (SQL) that exist for the purpose of referential integrity. Those same tables are represented in the code using enums since there is business logic around it. When localization become an issue, a localization table was added to each entity (containing the localizable fields). The enums are now being translated (via resource files) but a localization table also exists for each of the look-up tables.

I was hoping to get some sugestions on how to model this enum / look-up table relationship keeping in mind (entity framework 5) that the "look-up tables" now have child tables associated but the intention is to still keep the enums in the code..

Comment: Wow. It's rare to find a developer using EF which also cares about referential integrity. My company has all types of enums in code that don't have a matching type table for FK. Every time a new value gets added, I have to go to them to get the type value. They also don't realize how powerful the UPDATE command is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[House cleaning effort]
The way I've dealt with this since then has been

If the enum doesn't drive any business decision I typically don't have an enum for it.

If it's an enum that drives some sort of business decision, I typically make this a flags enum and the database entry would contain the flags enum value. There is typically an actual lookup table where those values are paired with labels and sometimes an extra bit of metadata.

I would then use some sort of cache mechanism to load those lookup table up-front (or lazily) in order to translate said enum into a proper label in the UI.

When I have some sort of metadata I either create a class with all the data that gets associated with the enum or I create a static class with extension methods for the enum that is responsible for extacting said metadata.

Ex:

enum Numbers { One, Two, Three }

Number.One.GetLabel();
Number.One.IsEven()

maybe keep a static field that caches that information after a first retrieval.